# Lots of Storyboards in XAML, huge file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

After spending a few ages writing out every combination of triggers, bindings and storyboards, I finally managed to get my program working. First time working with WPF, so I made a big mess. Now it's time to put on my refactoring hat and make the code neat and proper again!

That is, if I knew how. Could anyone experienced with WPF or XAML files help me out here and explain how to unmess this code? Suggesting a change of design is fine too, though like I said, this is the only way that I managed to actually get it working.

What the code is supposed to do, is dynamically be able to change sprite animations (by binding a .gif source to an Image), and dynamically "move around" the sprite on a preset animation, different animations depending on what happens in the rest of the code. Like, up and down, or in a circle, or to the corner of the screen and back. Etcetera.

I only copied three storyboards with small changes each per sprite in here for brevity, I suppose you can see what happens when I extend them even further..

```
<Window x:Class="Simplively.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:gif="clr-namespace:WpfAnimatedGif"
    gif:ImageBehavior.AnimateInDesignMode="True"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Background="Cyan" Margin="0" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid Width="1280" Height="720">
    <Image Source="Overlay.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="1280" Height="720"/>
    <Image Name="p1Sprite" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding PlayerOneSprite}" gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="Forever" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="239,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47" Source="Sprites/Bard.gif" RenderTransformOrigin="1,1">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="p1Scale" ScaleY="1" ScaleX="1"/>
                <SkewTransform x:Name="p1Skew" AngleY="0" AngleX="0"/>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="p1Rotate" Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="p1Translate" X="0" Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p1leftright">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p1updown">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p1ToCorner">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
    <Image Name="p2Sprite" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding PlayerTwoSprite}" gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="Forever" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="239,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47" Source="Sprites/Bard.gif">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p2leftright">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p2updown">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-64"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p2ToCorner">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-64"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
    <Image Name="p3Sprite" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding PlayerThreeSprite}" gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="Forever" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="239,396,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47" Source="Sprites/Bard.gif">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p3leftright">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p3updown">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-96"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p3ToCorner">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-96"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
        <Image Name="p4Sprite" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding PlayerFourSprite}" gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="Forever" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="239,448,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47" Source="Sprites/Bard.gif">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p4leftright">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p4updown">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-128"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StartAnimation}" Value="p4ToCorner">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-32"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0"
                                        To="-128"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                        />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="152" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" Source="Ffiigreendragon_psp.png"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="26,191,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PlayerOneName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your markup is inlining the styles, which has the effect of producing extremely redundant markup - as you've noticed.

You can define the resources of a window in its `Resources` property - step one would be to extract your inline styles into the `Window` tag:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
      ...
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
      ...
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then, you can refer to these styles with a `StaticResource` markup extension:

```
<Image Style="{StaticResource MyStyle1}">
    ...
</Image>
```

Depending on exactly what the "small value changes" are, you'll want to create a new `Style`, or put a `BasedOn` attribute to specify a `Style` to "derive" from another. An individual element can always override any value determined by its `Style`.

Once you've extracted the styles into the window's resources, you might want to move them to a `ResourceDictionary` so you can reuse the same styles in other windows, without having to redefine them over again.

Comment: Hmn, I think the biggest issue is that decide which of the four sprite's animation to activate, I need all kinds of variables like 'p1transform', 'p2transform', 'p3transform' etc.etc. for all the different things there are to animate. Is there a way to group the styles and still call on them with different names? Like.. only define "transform" once, and then do something like "p1.transform", "p2.transform", etc?

Comment: that could have been clearer if you had included the entire markup.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. Edited with the full thing in.